# Pairing Powerbeats Pro headphones with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, apple

I am attempting to pair my Powerbeats Pro headphones with my Alienware m15 laptop running Ubuntu 19.10. I have been able to pair the headphones with the Windows 10 installation on the laptop, the only issue pairing comes with the Ubuntu distribution. Any recommendations on how to proceed?

Answer (score 5):

Can you see your headphones when you turn on bluetooth on your laptop? If so, open a terminal and execute

```
    bluetoothctl
```

Then use `scan on` and `devices` to scan for and show device respectively.

Locate your headphones and then use `pair` followed by the address of your headphones to pair. After that you should be able to use the gui to connect to your headphones.

Also for reference you could look at: https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/bluetooth-headphones-ubuntu/

Comment: Also worked on Jammy! Thank you. I can't believe ubuntu UI doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issues with both my Bose Bluetooth Speaker and Powerbeats Pro. This is on my Razer Blade 15" 2018 laptop. Worked great on Win10 but Its been an issue for me in older version of Ubuntu and also 20.04.

I eventually replaced the NIC card on the Laptop. I believe the Powerbeats Pro require bluetooth 4.0 or higher to work. Not sure why it didn't like the old network card, as did supported 4.0.

I went from a **BCM94352Z** to a **Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650** Module and it's worked flawlessly ever sense. It feels like there are some compatibility issue with certain cards.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with my beats flex headphones that were previously paired with my machine. What worked for me was removing my device with

`bluetoothctl devices` to get the device id, and then
`bluetoothctl remove <dev>`
Hope this helps :3

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373583/18775

Though I had to do `[bluetooth]# remove XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` first to reset it.